# How to add a new field to a content type in drupal 8 module?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I have module, where i want to create new taxonomy field (if not exist) and attach it to the content type. I found easy way by exporting fields, but it will work only when I install module. I need to create them from time to time, automatically.

So by now I can create vocabulary and taxonomy terms:

```
$vocabulary = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Vocabulary::load($vid);
if (!$vocabulary) {
    $vocabulary = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Vocabulary::create(array(
          'vid' => $vid,
          'machine_name' => $vid,
          'name' => $name,
    ));
    $vocabulary->save();
}
```

create taxonomy term: (BTW is there some better way to check if term exist? taxonomy_term_load_multiple_by_name is old d7 function, but i cant find other way)

```
if($terms = taxonomy_term_load_multiple_by_name($name, $vid))
{
    $term = reset($terms);
}
else
{
    $term = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::create([
        'name' => $name, 
        'vid' => $vid,
    ])->save();
}
```

Node entity has only metod to check field definitions, and i cant find any possibility to create/attach field. I found only toturials and code examples to create brand new type of field, but no glue how to attach fields to a content type.

Comment: For your question on how to better check if a term exists: You can load a term just like you create one using Term::load($tid) or Term::load_multiple($tids). For your actual question: I think you're gonna have to load the entity_type and attach your vocabulary on it. Haven't done this before so can't really say for sure.

Comment: term load will get term by id, I want to get it by name ;) So this way or entityquery way